# High oil pressure in a marine engine

Tags: oil, diesel

High oil pressure in my marine Perkins 4108 diesel showing 80 on the gauge, oil and filters recently changed, wiring checked and ok it runs an alternator to charge the batteries and when disconnected goes back to 35-40psi but it should run the alternator without the pressure going up ?

Comment: Is it an electrical or mechanical gauge?

Comment: Do the RPMs go up? Or is the oil pressure the only thing affected?

Comment: Did you change the oil weight?

Comment: when you say disconnected it goes back to 35-40 psi. what are you disconnecting?? is it a 12 vdc or 24 vdc system??